# getting FORM-1.PDF name in browser when generating merged pdf through PDFMergerUtility class using java

Tags: pdf

I am getting FORM-1.PDF name in the browser when I am generating a pdf which merged document.There are two documents that I am merging .I am using PDFMergerUtility class in java to merge the files in one pdf .Can anyone help how can I remove FORM-1.PDF name .I am not manual putting the file name still its displaying FORM-1.PDF.  Can anyone explain why its taking that name?
Please find the screenshot for reference.
[image]

Comment: Your question might have got more attention if you had mentioned the pdf library you use and tagged your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer .We need to change the meta data of pdf document after merging the document.